# Password blur event not showing

Tags: javascript, html, blur

Im trying to have a blur event for when username and password are to short it says username/password must be x long.
For some reason it only works on my username and I have no clue why

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <h1>List King</h1>
      <h2>New Account</h2>
      <form method="post" action="http://www.example.org/register">

        <label for="username">Create a username: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <div id="feedback"></div>

        <label for="password1">Create a password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="password"/>
        <div id="feedback"></div>

        <input type="submit" value="sign up" />

      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="event-listener.js"></script>
  </body>
```

javascript

```
function checkUsername() {                             
  var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');            
if (this.value.length < 5) {                        
    elMsg.textContent = 'Username must be 5 characters or more'; 
  } else {                                             
elMsg.textContent = '';                            
 } 
 }



var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');  
elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkUsername, false);


function checkPassword() {
var elMsg = document.getElementId('feedback');
if (this.value.length < 6){
    elMsg.textContent = 'Password must be 6 characters or more';
} else {
    elMsg.textContent = ' ';
}       
}
var elPassword = doucment.getElementById('password');
elPassword.addEventListener('blur', checkPassword, false);
```

Comment: syntax errorrs, open console and fix them first

Comment: worked perfectly fine for me?

Comment: doucment, document.getElementId

Comment: you have 2 div's with the same id of `feedback`. Id's have to be unique or the browser won't pick the div you expect.

Comment: use "code" button to insert your code, it will help not to waste your and our time :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page">
          <h1>List King</h1>
          <h2>New Account</h2>
          <form method="post" action="http://www.example.org/register">

            <label for="username">Create a username: </label>
            <input type="text" id="username" />
            <div id="feedback"></div>

            <label for="password1">Create a password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="password"/>      <div id="feedback1"></div>


            <input type="submit" value="sign up" />

          </form>
        </div>
        <script src="event-listener.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>


function checkUsername() {                             // Declare function
  var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');     // Get feedback element
  if (this.value.length < 5) {                         // If username too short
    elMsg.textContent = 'Username must be 5 characters or more'; // Set msg
  } else {                                             // Otherwise
    elMsg.textContent = '';                            // Clear msg
  }
}



var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');  // Get username input
// When it loses focus call checkUsername()
elUsername.addEventListener('blur', checkUsername, false);


function CheckPassword() {                             // Declare function
  var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback1');     // Get feedback element
  if (this.value.length < 6) {                         // If username too short
    elMsg.textContent = 'Password must be 6 characters or more'; // Set msg
  } else {                                             // Otherwise
    elMsg.textContent = '';                            // Clear msg
  }

}var elPassword = document.getElementById('password');  // Get username input
elPassword.addEventListener('blur', CheckPassword, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a plunkr example here< https://plnkr.co/edit/MBkFQSEjbKIAFPDOFUTW?p=preview >. You have few spelling mistakes in your code and used the same id to show the message. I used html5 tags for blur event instead of event listeners.

```
function checkUsername() {                             
    var usernameLength=document.getElementById('username').value.length;
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback1');            
    if (usernameLength < 5) {                        
      elMsg.textContent = 'Username must be 5 characters or more'; 
    } else {                                             
      elMsg.textContent = 'good';                            
    } 
   }

  function checkPassword() {
    var elPassword = document.getElementById('password');
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback2');
    if (elPassword.value.length < 6){
      elMsg.textContent = 'Password must be 6 characters or more';
    } else {
      elMsg.textContent = ' ';
    }       
  }
```